# IAP SKErrorDomain Code=0 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I know posts related to this error are numerous, though non of them proposed a solution working for me. I'm trying to do the in-app purchase tutorial of Ray Wenderlinch : everytime I try to perform a purchase with a Sandbox account, I get the following error right after I entered my account ID ad before the "confirm purchase" alert controller appears (showing by the way that I'm running in sandbox environment).

```
Transaction Error: Optional("Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible"), 
0, [AnyHashable("NSLocalizedDescription"): Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible], 
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible}
```

I've tried these already without success :

- iTunes Connect account configured, Paid Applications contract is in Effect;
- BundleID, IAP ID entered in Xcode both match the ones on iTunes;
- I've been unlogged from AppStore before running the app;
- App purchase is clear for purchase;
- I've waited several hours after creating both the IAP and the Sandbox account;
- the payment added in SKPaymentQueue has the right product with the right productIdentifier (which again matches the one set up in iTunes);
- Version set in Xcode matches the one on iTunes (1.0);
- I've tried setting the Localization native development region to France so it matches the sandbox account localization;

(I may have forgotten things that I tried but these are the solutions proposed in the other posts plus own ideas)

The code should be correct as it's the final project proposed on the website (link below), modulo the IDs, which has been corrected for swift 3 and iOS 10. I'm running it on my iPhone iOS 10 also.

Here is the link for the code :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial

Thank you in advance for your help !!

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the problem came from Apple : the Sandbox system was down.